# Plug-in: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout

when I'm trying to add a Toggle Button I get an error, would you please help me here?
I added a text.xml as a layout and I'm filling it.

[image: Included the image in question]

and the description is:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at android.view.ShadowPainter.createDropShadow(ShadowPainter.java:116)
    at android.view.ShadowPainter.createDropShadow(ShadowPainter.java:48)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.getPathShadow(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:140)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawShadow(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:77)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15017)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15017)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15117)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15022)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15117)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:587)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:334)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:349)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:519)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1584)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1309)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.onXmlModelChanged(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1267)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegateXmlModelChanged(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:402)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.xmlModelChanged(CommonXmlEditor.java:329)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor$XmlModelStateListener.modelChanged(AndroidXmlEditor.java:1653)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.wrapEditXmlModel(AndroidXmlEditor.java:1114)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.wrapUndoEditXmlModel(AndroidXmlEditor.java:1190)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.MoveGesture.drop(MoveGesture.java:396)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GestureManager$CanvasDropListener.drop(GestureManager.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DNDListener.handleEvent(DNDListener.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1085)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1070)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget.Drop(DropTarget.java:456)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget$3.method6(DropTarget.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COMObject.callback6(COMObject.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COM.DoDragDrop(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DragSource.drag(DragSource.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DragSource.access$0(DragSource.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DragSource$1.handleEvent(DragSource.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

Comment: Hey guys! Anybody could help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Graphic Layout, my original screen was Nexus One, when I changed the screen to an xhdpi screen, no matter which one, errors went away. Then I tried to change it back to Nexus one again, which is an hdpi, and all errors went away. I still don't understand the cause of the error, but I guess arrangement of Toggle Button in xhdpi caused the problem, and after that its position was set in a bigger screen, conversation between screen is possible. I don't know I'm just guessing. :)